# C++: how do I create an object in stack memory that points to the object I am generating it from?

Tags: c++, pointers

I have a class Foo with a constructor Foo(Bar * b). I want a function inside of the class Bar that returns a Foo that points to that Bar. I try:

```
Foo& Bar::make_foo() {
  Foo f((Bar*)this);
  return f;
}
```

but then G++ tells me:

```
error: variable ‘Foo f’ has initializer but incomplete type
```

now I know this would work fine in heap memory:

```
Foo* Bar::make_foo() {
  Foo * f = new Foo((Bar*)this);
  return f;
}
```

---

Edit: apparently the problem was due to an incomplete class defintion. However I am still curious if there is an appropriate idiom for returning an object in stack memory.

Comment: Does it really work fine with dynamic allocation? Have you tried it? Nonetheless, you'll have a problem with your stack version. The `f` object will be destroyed at the end of `make_foo` and the returned reference will be left dangling.

Comment: What does your `Foo` declaration look like?

Comment: Yes, this is what I'm realizing. Is there an idiom for doing this in stack memory, or should I not bother?

Comment: @DavidPfau: For auto-duration objects (often incorrectly called "stack" objects), the norm is to return the object. A reference or pointer will be invalid as soon as the function returns. C++ will often (but not always) elide the temporary object construction and the copy anyway and just directly modify the object you're assigning the result to. C++11 will let you specify a move constructor and move assignment operator, for those cases where a copy would or should not work for some reason...but really, it's usually not worth it unless you absolutely need to.  Just return the actual object.

Answer (score 1):

This code is wrong ANYWAY, since it's returning an object on the stack, which means that once you have returned from the function, that space is available for other objects to be stored in - that's not going to end at all well.

```
Foo& Bar::make_foo() {
  Foo f((Bar*)this);
  return f;
}
```

As long as `Bar` is declared as it should be, you should be able to do this fine - aside from the concern with "you are using stack-space that is going to be freed".

Comment: What a strange answer. "You should be able to do this fine - aside from the fact that it will not work." :-)

Comment: What I mean is that if you ONLY need `f` inside the function, and Bar is declared properly, it will work. Returning a local a reference to a local variable is obviously still wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me (http://codepad.org/feWQYjtt). Note: I have slightly changed the signature of `make-foo`, returning reference of local object does not make sense.

```
struct Bar;
struct Foo {
    Foo( Bar * ) {}
};

struct Bar {
    Foo make_foo() {     // Signature changed
        return Foo( this );
    }
};

int main() {
    Bar barObj;
    Foo fooObj = barObj.make_foo();
    (void) fooObj;
}
```

Comment: How many times is foo copied?  Answer left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: Interesting comment :-), how about Return-Value-Optimization? See the comment (in the question) from cHao.

Comment: C++11 does confuse this, but even for older versions of C++, all you have to do is add the possibility of returning one of two Foo's in make_foo and RVO doesn't work anymore.

Comment: Perhaps, `return Foo( this );`, i.e. returning a unnamed object would be better?